# detailed scanning of unwanted files

Tags: vb.net

i am trying to make launcher for my server, but i am kinda worried, is there any way that i can make a list of unwanted files in browsed directory, and if script finds any of those files when i press this button it will show like this warning message, ive tried a couple of things but none works

```
 Imports System.IO

Public Class imeprezime

    Private Sub Label1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If (FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then
            TextBox2.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath

        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub connect_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles connect.Click

            Dim cleoPath As String
            Dim filePath As String
            filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(TextBox2.Text, "gta_sa.exe")
        cleoPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(TextBox2.Text, "cleo")

            If File.Exists(filePath) Then

            If Directory.Exists(cleoPath) Then

                MsgBox("Pronasli smo cleo fajl u vasem GTA root folderu. Da se konektujete na server morate ga obrisati.")

            Else

                Dim p() As Process

                p = Process.GetProcessesByName("gta_sa")

                If p.Count > 0 Then
                    MsgBox("Vec imate pokrenut GTA San Andreas.")
                Else
                    ' Process is not running
                End If

            End If


        Else
            MsgBox("Da se konektujete morate locirati GTA San Andreas folder.")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub imeprezime_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: How is this related to C?

Comment: I did put c and vb but it choose c sorry

Comment: Try starting to do good things by extracting and separating functionalities outside of your button event handler. Define one function to determine if "X" amount of processes with name "Y" are found, define other function to check whether files/directories exists, and then... call them consecutivelly at the right time. And finally, explain what means "none works".

Comment: Sorry, i dont really understand that with processes, by none works i mean that i've tried for example
cleoPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(TextBox2.Text, "cleo", "sobeit", "aim") 

but then i found out that that command only adds on it which means it will search for /cleo/sobeit/aim and not all of them together, sorry if i confused you but i only started learning vb today, and i think i've done a good job, but checking multiple files is what is buggin me